# Politely asking "Why is this taking so long??"

Tags: politeness, email

I am trying to write a business email and, as English is not my first language, I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with a really polite way of saying the following:

> Hi, It's been a week since I e-mailed you asking you for the documentation, and you haven't replied yet. I'm in a hurry, so, would you please send them to me as soon as possible?"

Here's what I've come up with so far:

> I am looking forward to receiving these documents, as they are essential to our development. Would you please forward them as soon as possible?

But I feel that "Would you please forward them as soon as possible" is not polite enough. Is it? Are there any other options here?

Comment: "Sir, your flagrant delay causes me much consternation. I demand that you forward the necessary documents at your earliest possible moment lest I be forced to demand satisfaction via a glove-slap fight!"

Comment: Hahaha that's really funny! To bad I don't speak "15th century" to reply in the same manner :-)

Comment: Another politeness tweak: because sometimes things do go astray, say "I haven't received" instead of "you haven't sent" when talking about past exchanges.  Even if you're certain the other person never sent it, this is more polite.

Comment: "At your earliest convenience" can be a slightly more polite synonym for "as soon as possible", as it indicates urgency but with a little less pushiness.

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/69101/8278

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you come up with is polite enough. Another option is something along the lines of,

> I hope to move forward on this project next week. Please send the requested documentation by Friday; if that is not possible, please let me know when I can expect to receive the documentation.

It's a little more pointed but gives a deadline (useful) while acknowledging that their timescale may not be the same as yours (polite).

Comment: A specific deadline is much better than 'As soon as possible'.  I would go for "I need the documentation by Friday, please let me know if that is not possible" .. but pretty much the same